# Message "Do not dispose objects multiple times" in Code Analysis with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have this code in my C#  winforms application:

```
SqlDataReader reader = dataObject.EjecutarConsulta();
try
{
   //Some stuff
}
finally
{
   reader.Close();
   reader.Dispose();
}
```

Now, in the Code Analysis i'm getting `Do not dispose objects multiple times` message. Why is this? I must to say that between the `try` block i don't close or dispose anything.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a using statement?

Comment: I'm considering using that statement (using) but i would like to know why is giving this message anyway.

Comment: You have fallen victim to the **superstitious dispose** pattern. You close the object multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

[DbDataReader.Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59cbyee3.aspx) internally calls [DbDataReader.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.close.aspx)

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)        
        this.Close();        
}
```

So, with

```
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
```

You are putting reader to disposed state two times in a row.

UPDATE: [CA2202](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) warning description states, that Close() can be treated as Dispose() equivalent:

> A method implementation contains code paths that could cause multiple
>   calls to IDisposable.Dispose or a Dispose equivalent, such as a
>   Close() method on some types, on the same object.

That's why you see multiple *dispose* warning.

Comment: I understand that.. so i shouldn't call the Close method, but this message is about the Dispose multiple times no Closing multiple times

Comment: Why two times? You say that `Dispose` internally calls `Close`... so, i'm calling `Close` two times.. no `Dispose`.. i dont understand..

Comment: So when Code Analysis say's `Do not Dispose` it could be `Dispose` OR `Close`?... now i understand :)

Comment: @Phoenix_uy updated answer - `Close` is treated as equivalent for `Dispose` in this case

Comment: @Phoenix_uy yes, exactly :) I think you will see same behavior for streams. Btw consider to use `using` statement instead of manually writing `try catch Dispose`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = dataObject.EjecutarConsulta()){
    try
{
   //Code Goes Here
   }
}catch(Exception ex){
Messagebox.Show(ex.toString());
}
```

By using the `using` statement it makes sure the objects have been properly disposed off, and I'm sure as you heard that; the .Close() method Disposes of the object so there's no need for the .Dispose() method.